# handling encoding error with xml with beautiful soup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

My xml file is encoding thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I am trying to parse this file using beautiful soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fd = open("xmlsample.xml")  
soup = BeautifulSoup(fd,'lxml-xml',from_encoding='utf-8')
```

But this results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gregg_000\Desktop\Python 
Experiments\NRE_XMLtoCSV\NRE_XMLtoCSV\bs1.py", line 4, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fd,'lxml-xml', from_encoding='utf-8')
  File 
"C:\Users\gregg_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
```

packages\bs4__init__.py", line 245, in **init**
        markup = markup.read()
      File

> "C:\Users\gregg_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp125 
>     2.py", line 23, in decode
>          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 
>      5343910: character maps to undefined

My sense is that Python is wanting to use the default cp1252 character set.  How can I force utf-8 without having to resort to the command line?  (I'm in a set-up where I can't easily force global changes to the python set up).

Comment: Can you please edit the question to show the complete error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add the encoding to your `open()` call (it's an acceptable argument as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open) indicate). By default in Windows (at least in my install), the default is, as you guessed, cp1252.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fd = open("xmlsample.xml", encoding='utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(fd,'lxml-xml',from_encoding='utf-8')
```